# Can you help me with U-SQL Custom Outputter that generated .Avro file

Tags: avro, azure-data-lake, u-sql, argument-dependent-lookup

I am looking for a U-SQL Custom Outputter that generated .Avro file. Can you help me in providing with any suggestion or sample?

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of an Avro custom inputter in github [here](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/AvroExamples).  Consider converting it to a custom outputter.

If you feel strongly about Avro support in U-SQL you can vote for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/16616362-support-avro-in-azure-data-lake-analytics).

Comment: how do we output as an avro file?